# Make groovy metaclass methods available globally

Tags: groovy, metaclass

I have a groovy script, Bootstrap.groovy, where I have defined several metaclass methods on the String class. I have my test cases in another file Test.groovy. How do I make the metaclass methods available in the Test.groovy, when manipulating String? (Iow, how do I make the metaclass methods globally available in other scripts/programs)?

(I did search and find some related questions, but they did not answer this specifically. Im using Groovy 1.8.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way to do this: just call `evaluate(new File("ch8/Bootstrap.groovy"))` in `Test.groovy`. Previously I was trying `new GroovyShell().evaluate()`, but thats not required. I could directly call the `evaluate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the DelegatingMetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Delegating+Meta+Class) to make these additions to the String class globally visible.